# Invalid controller specified (auth)

Tags: zend-framework

I have been trying to write an basic authentication system as part of a project which I am supposed to be using in order to learn about the Zend Framework. I have been using the Zend CLI tools to help create my application. I have a module called Admin, within which I have a controllers called Auth. However, when I try to navigate to the controller in a browser I get the following error:

```
An error occurred

Page not found

Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (auth)

Stack trace:

#0 /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  
Request Parameters:

array (
  'module' => 'admin',
  'controller' => 'auth',
  'action' => 'index',
)
```

You can view this for yourself by heading over to zend.danielgroves.net

As far as I can tell everything is named correctly, take a look at the screenshot below to see how everything was structured by the CLI tools. This is the guide I was following in attempt to build this login system http://akrabat.com/zend-auth-tutorial/. I had just reached the part with the login screen screenshot (first image).

[image: Zend Directory/File structure]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

My application.ini file post the change suggested by @ByteNudger:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

resources.db.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = ""
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = ""

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

resources.modules[] = "" (section [bootstrap])

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

The PHP error generated by the application.ini change:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'syntax error, unexpected '(' in /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/application/configs/application.ini on line 20' in /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php:182
Stack trace:
#0 /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php(202): Zend_Config_Ini->_parseIniFile('/home/www-data/...')
#1 /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php(126): Zend_Config_Ini->_loadIniFile('/home/www-data/...')
#2 /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Application.php(386): Zend_Config_Ini->__construct('/home/www-data/...', 'development')
#3 /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Application.php(85): Zend_Application->_loadConfig('/home/www-data/...')
#4 /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/public/index.php(24): Zend_Application->__construct('development', '/home/www-data/...')
#5 {main}
  thrown in /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php on line 182
```

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, i've just tried what was suggested in the answer by Ross Smith II below.  My application.ini file now reads:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/admin/controllers"

resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

resources.db.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = ""
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = ""

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "admin"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/admin/layouts/scripts/"
resources.modules[] =

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

And I am getting this error in browser:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:248 Stack trace: #0 /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1 /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #2 /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() #3 /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run() #4 {main} Next exception 'Zend_Controller_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)#0 /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(O in /home/www-data/zend.danielgroves.net/htdocs/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 336
```

See for yourself: http://zend.danielgroves.net/admin/auth/

**Edit 3**

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/admin/controllers"

resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

resources.db.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = ""
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = ""

resources.modules[] = ""

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Comment: Do you enabled module resources in your `application.ini` with the line `resources.modules[] = ""` (`section [bootstrap]`)?

Comment: @ByteNudger See my edit in the post above, unfortunately it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry `(section [bootstrap])` shouldn't be in the `application.ini`. It was only mend to be as comment. Please remove this and try it again.

Comment: Unfortunately still no change.  Is there any other information I could provide that might help to diagnose it?

Comment: Did you use the changes from me and Ross Smith II at same time? If yes only use the `application.ini` from your first **EDIT 1** and remove the error I mentioned before. Also use lower case name for your directories names in `modules`.

Comment: I had the modules directory as lower case, and used the `application.ini` files from Edit 1, but changed any mentions of `Admin` to `admin` to match the updated modules directory name.  Will post the copy now.

Comment: `resources.modules[] = ""` will cause you nothing but grief. `resources.modules[] =` is correct, per http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html

Comment: Ok, I've removed the quote marks.  If you take a look at http://zend.danielgroves.net/admin/auth/ you can see their is some kind of `Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception` being thrown with the message `Invalid controller specified (error)`.

Comment: Please remove the `resources.frontController.controllerDirectory` line and add `resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"` in your **EDIT 3**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was something I did some months back

You can see the whole code at  https://github.com/harikt/blog

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
autoloadernamespaces[] = "BinaryKitten"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.view[] = 

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

In Bootstrap.php

```
<?php
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    public function _initControllerPlugins()
    {
        $plugin = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->registerPlugin(
            new BinaryKitten_ModuleConfig()
        );
    }

    public function _initAutoload()
    {
        $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
            array(
                'namespace' => '',
                'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . "/modules/default"
            )
        );
        return $moduleLoader;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Getting modules to work correctly in Zend can be very challenging. We've encountered numerous unexpected issues, such as multiple database connections being initialized (one per module).

First, I would change your `application.ini` to include the following:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/Admin/controllers"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "Admin"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/Admin/layouts/scripts/"

resources.modules[] =
```

If that doesn't help, try changing `Admin` to `admin` as we've never used capitalized module names.

If you're still stuck, please post your `application.ini` file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately I still don't be seeming to go anywhere, but have added my application.ini file above.

Comment: I should also note here, that I did try renaming the `Admin` folder to `admin`, and changed each instance in the `application.ini` file respectively.

Answer (score 0):

All I ever add to make modules work in applications with ZF 1.11 is these three lines in my application.ini.

```
resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "controllers"
resources.modules = ""
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

also to make autoloadiong work correctly make sure you don't forget to put an empty `Bootstrap.php` in each module that looks like:

```
<?php
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    //put your code here
}
```

also it may help with some configurations to specify the prefix of the default module, mine looks like:

```
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = ""
```

and my default module is the original application directories for controllers,models and views. Much like your current configuration.

**[EDIT]**

Ok you've gotten into a bit of a mess, perhaps you take alook at Rob Allen's tutorial on [modules in ZF 1.x](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/bootstrapping-modules-in-zf-1-8/) that's where I learned.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've followed these steps and still don't seem to be getting anywhere.  It seems that whatever I change the error stays the same.